# Terminology : Action of translate one programme in some language to another one

Tags: terminology

Pretty basic question. What's the term / word used for name the action of translate one program in some language to another one, simply "translate" ? I was thinking that "porting" was a good one but according to Wikipedia it seems not. (For example: from C to C++)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization

Comment: I would expect "porting" to mean "translating" a program to work on different hardware.

Comment: How about compiling?

Comment: Thank you CBroe, My question is only about programming language

Comment: Yes, Carcignicate, that's what I've understand for "porting" and that's why I'm searching for an another term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Transcompilation is the term you are looking for:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler

Comment: Does it suits for the human action to do it ? For exemple, if I was translating a code in JAVA to C++ all the day and a friend ask me "What did you do today ?", can I answer "oh.. nothing, I was just transcompilating some code.."

Comment: According to Wikipedia seems like you can say "trans-compiling" , "transpiling"  or "source to source compiling".

Good luck with that :)